# Find the velocity of the image wrt ground.The mirror is at rest and the object is moving perpendicular to the axis with $5~\mathrm{cm/s}$ as in figure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection

Find the velocity of the image with respect to the ground. The mirror is at rest and the object is moving perpendicular to the axis with $5~\mathrm{cm/s}$ as in figure.

[image]

From [this solution](https://sahay.guru/find-the-velocity-of-image-w-r-t-ground-the-mirror-is-at-rest-and-the-object-is-moving/), I understood that the question is asking about the velocity of the image in $Y$-direction.

I assumed the right hand side of the mirror to be positive and applied the mirror formula. When $$u=-30\mathrm{cm},\quad f=-20\mathrm{cm},\quad v=-60\mathrm{cm}$$

Therefore $m=-2$ and $H_o=x$ which implies $H_i=2x$.

After $1\mathrm{s}$
$$u=-25\mathrm{cm},\quad f=-20\mathrm{cm},\quad 
v=-100\mathrm{cm}$$

Therefore $m=-4$ and $H_o=x$ which implies $H_i=4x$.

Therefore the speed of height is $2x/\mathrm{s}$ and it seems that the velocity will depend on height of object.

But the answer is $10\mathrm{cm/s}$.

Where am I wrong ?? Is it possible to do the sum in this way ??

Comment: You can't talk about the Y direction until after you define a coordinate system.

Comment: As given, the focal length of a concave mirror is positive. You can work on the left side of the mirror with all distances positive. (What you did does work.)

Answer (score 1):

As you note, if the object starts on the axis of symmetry and moves a perpendicular distance of $H_o$ (its own height), then the image will move a distance of 2$H_o$ in the opposite direction.  The velocity of the image is twice that of the object.